# Which V8 API methods require a context?

Tags: v8

I've noticed that some V8 API methods do not require that a context be entered, while others do.  For example, `String::New` works without a context, but `String::Utf8Value` won't work—instead, the process crashes.

Is there a general rule as to what portions of the API require a context be entered, and which ones don't?  The documentation doesn't seem to specify when a context is required.

Comment: I'm looking for this answer as well. :)  I noticed that I don't need a context for an object template because you need it to created a context! :)  I think I read somewhere that only script execution and object instantiation needs a context, but I'd like to confirm it.